# Report progress properly in this file operation?

Tags: .net, vb.net, file, math, progress

This method splits a file into chunks, I would like to report the progress (the percent) of the remaining chunks and the total remaining bytes to accomplish the task.

I've messed my head with the arithmetic operations, someone could help me?

Please note in the code the instructions where I need to report the progress, I used labels just for test, I will keep the values in variables:

```
Label1.Text = ...
```

Here is the method:

```
    Public Sub SplitFile(ByVal InputFile As String,
                        ByVal ChunkSize As Long,
                        Optional ByVal ChunkName As String = Nothing,
                        Optional ByVal ChunkExt As String = Nothing,
                        Optional ByVal Overwrite As Boolean = False)

       ' FileInfo instance of the input file.
       Dim fInfo As New IO.FileInfo(InputFile)

       ' The buffer to read data and write the chunks.
       Dim Buffer As Byte() = New Byte() {}

       ' The buffer length.
       Dim BufferSize As Integer = 1048576I ' 1048576 = 1 mb | 33554432 = 32 mb | 67108864 = 64 mb

       ' Counts the length of the current chunk file.
       Dim BytesWritten As Long = 0L

       ' The total amount of chunks to create.
       Dim ChunkCount As Integer = CInt(Math.Floor(fInfo.Length / ChunkSize))

       ' Keeps track of the current chunk.
       Dim ChunkIndex As Integer = 0I

       ' A zero-filled string to enumerate the chunk files.
       Dim Zeros As String = String.Empty

       ' The given filename for each chunk.
       Dim ChunkFile As String = String.Empty

       ' The chunk file basename.
       ChunkName = If(String.IsNullOrEmpty(ChunkName),
                      IO.Path.Combine(fInfo.DirectoryName, IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(fInfo.Name)),
                      IO.Path.Combine(fInfo.DirectoryName, ChunkName))

       ' The chunk file extension.
       ChunkExt = If(String.IsNullOrEmpty(ChunkExt),
                     fInfo.Extension.Substring(1I),
                     ChunkExt)

       ' If ChunkSize is bigger than filesize then...
       If ChunkSize >= fInfo.Length Then
           Throw New OverflowException("'ChunkSize' should be smaller than the Filesize.")
           Exit Sub

           ' For cases where a chunksize is smaller than the buffersize.
       ElseIf ChunkSize < BufferSize Then
           BufferSize = CInt(ChunkSize)

       End If ' ChunkSize <>...

       ' If not file-overwrite is allowed then...
       If Not Overwrite Then

           For Index As Integer = 0I To (ChunkCount)

               ' Set chunk filename.
               Zeros = New String("0", CStr(ChunkCount).Length - CStr(Index + 1I).Length)
               ChunkFile = String.Format("{0}.{1}.{2}", ChunkName, Zeros & CStr(Index + 1I), ChunkExt)

               ' If chunk file already exists then...
               If IO.File.Exists(ChunkFile) Then

                   Throw New IO.IOException(String.Format("File already exist: {0}", ChunkFile))
                   Exit Sub

               End If ' IO.File.Exists(ChunkFile)

           Next Index

           Zeros = String.Empty
           ChunkFile = String.Empty

       End If ' Overwrite

       ' Open the file to start reading bytes.
       Using InputStream As New IO.FileStream(fInfo.FullName, IO.FileMode.Open)

           Using BinaryReader As New IO.BinaryReader(InputStream)

               While (InputStream.Position < InputStream.Length)

                   ' Set chunk filename.
                   Zeros = New String("0", CStr(ChunkCount).Length - CStr(ChunkIndex + 1I).Length)
                   ChunkFile = String.Format("{0}.{1}.{2}", ChunkName, Zeros & CStr(ChunkIndex + 1I), ChunkExt)

                   ' Reset written byte-length counter.
                   BytesWritten = 0L

                   ' Create the chunk file to Write the bytes.
                   Using OutputStream As New IO.FileStream(ChunkFile, IO.FileMode.Create)

                       Using BinaryWriter As New IO.BinaryWriter(OutputStream)

                           ' Read until reached the end-bytes of the input file.
                           While (BytesWritten < ChunkSize) AndAlso (InputStream.Position < InputStream.Length)

                               ' Read bytes from the original file (BufferSize byte-length).
                               Buffer = BinaryReader.ReadBytes(BufferSize)

                               ' Write those bytes in the chunk file.
                               BinaryWriter.Write(Buffer)

                               ' Increment the size counter.
                               BytesWritten += Buffer.Count

                               ' Use the written bytes of this chunk to calculate the total remaining bytes of the operation (not only for this chunk)...
                               ' Label1.Text = CDbl((100L / ChunkSize) * BytesWritten) / (ChunkIndex / ChunkCount) '/ fInfo.Length
                               Application.DoEvents()

                           End While ' (BytesWritten < ChunkSize) AndAlso (InputStream.Position < InputStream.Length)

                           OutputStream.Flush()

                       End Using ' BinaryWriter

                   End Using ' OutputStream

                   ChunkIndex += 1I 'Increment file counter

                   ' Report progress of remaining chunks...
                   ' Label1.Text = CDbl((100I / ChunkCount) * (ChunkIndex))

               End While ' InputStream.Position < InputStream.Length

           End Using ' BinaryReader

       End Using ' InputStream

   End Sub
```

> UPDATE:

With this I can print the progress when a chunk is created, its ok but its very unprecise progress lets say we have to split a file in chunks of 3 GB each one, then I only can report a progress-change after some time when a chunk finished to create:

```
Debug.WriteLine(((ChunkIndex) / ChunkCount) * 100I)
```

That's the reason why I'm trying to work a progress report when the bytes are written in each chunk, that way I could report a progress-change quickly every second, note this part in the code above, here is where I need help:

```
' Use the written bytes of this chunk to calculate the total remaining bytes of the operation (not only for this chunk)...
' Label1.Text = CDbl((100L / ChunkSize) * BytesWritten) / (ChunkIndex / ChunkCount) '/ fInfo.Length
```

Comment: There's a lot of code in there... What's the actual issue? Are you getting an error?

Comment: @Brandon, in the question (the part that is not code ) I've explained the issue, I'm trying to get a percentage and I've explained where is the instruction in the code.

Comment: @Plutonix thanks for the info, that helps me to print the progress but I'm working on the other (more precise) progress when adding the bytes into the chunk, it's in the code, could you help me with that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few style things:

It's usually a good idea to name local variables in lower case. It makes it a lot easier to read and follow your code. When they begin in uppercase, they will be mistaken for method names (maybe this is just my preference)

It's not necessary to suffix numbers with `I` or `L`. When you declare the variable, the compiler will know what to do when you explicitly specify the type.

To answer your question:

If I understand that you just want more granular progress data, simply declare a variable to hold the total size of the file and subtract the bytes you've written after each chunked buffer operation. Add this declaration:

```
    Dim bytesRemaining = fInfo.Length
```

and then change your `While` loop from this:

```
While (BytesWritten < ChunkSize) AndAlso (InputStream.Position < InputStream.Length)

    ' Read bytes from the original file (BufferSize byte-length).
    Buffer = BinaryReader.ReadBytes(BufferSize)

    ' Write those bytes in the chunk file.
    BinaryWriter.Write(Buffer)

    ' Increment the size counter.
    BytesWritten += Buffer.Count

    ' Use the written bytes of this chunk to calculate the total remaining bytes of the operation (not only for this chunk)...
    ' Label1.Text = CDbl((100L / ChunkSize) * BytesWritten) / (ChunkIndex / ChunkCount) '/ fInfo.Length
    Application.DoEvents()

End While ' (BytesWritten < ChunkSize) AndAlso (InputStream.Position < InputStream.Length)
```

To this:

```
While (BytesWritten < ChunkSize) AndAlso (InputStream.Position < InputStream.Length)

    ' Read bytes from the original file (BufferSize byte-length).
    Buffer = BinaryReader.ReadBytes(BufferSize)

    ' Write those bytes in the chunk file.
    BinaryWriter.Write(Buffer)

    ' Increment the size counter.
    BytesWritten += Buffer.Count

    bytesRemaining -= Buffer.Count

    ' Use the written bytes of this chunk to calculate the total remaining bytes of the operation (not only for this chunk)...

    If bytesRemaining > 0 Then
        Label1.Text = (bytesRemaining / fInfo.Length) * 100
    End If

    Application.DoEvents()

End While ' (BytesWritten < ChunkSize) AndAlso (InputStream.Position < InputStream.Length)
```

You'll have to format the percentage how you want it.

Also, note that I did not test this for every possible case. It's possible that on the last file something crazy will go wrong, you'll have to fix that when it happens.

Comment: Thankyou for the help, but in the last file it gives a `1144058700` and before in the penultimate file it gives me a `1048575900`, I really don't understand how to get a percentage from those values, they seems wrong, could you verify your code or give me instructions to procceed the value formatting? thankyou

Comment: That's because I copied over the calculation incorrectly. Give me a minute to fix it.

Comment: I edited my answer, try that instead. Also, the solution I provided will give you the percentage of chunking completed, not the percentage remaining. Remove the -100 for percentage remaining.

Comment: I think that the calculation still bad, the last file gives me an `infinite`, the penultimate file gives me a `1098,18312827022`, without the `-100` the same but instead a `1098` its increased by 100 giving me a `1198,18312827022` i'm just trying to split a file of 10,9 mb into 1 mb chunks, this is the code: `SplitFile("C:\test.mp3", 1024 ^ 2, "Test.Part", "mp3", True)`

Comment: The last file gives Infinity because it's dividing by zero. That's what I meant when I said I didn't test all the cases. I'm not sure how you're using the code I gave, but I successfully split a 115mb text file into 1024kb chunks multiple times and got proper percentage updates. You are doing something differently.

Comment: I edited the answer again. I copied the code incorrectly when I updated the answer last time. NOW it should work

Comment: really thankyou for your time, now it calculates the proper values but it goes in the reverse way, I mean the progress goes from `100 to 0` instead `0 to 100`. I've resolved the operation in a ugly way calculating a negative value and then converting that value to positive but I wonder that you could give me a proper solution than mine: `Math.Abs((bytesRemaining / fInfo.Length) * 100 - (100))` with the proper progress fix that returns the code that you've provided finally we could say that this question is solved, thankyou!

Comment: 100 - Math.Floor((bytesRemaining / fInfo.Length) * 100). If my answer solved the question, please mark it as accepted.

Comment: Finally I get the desired percentages:  `TotalProgress=(TotalSize - SizeRemaining) * (100I / TotalSize)`, `ChunkProgress:(100I / ChunkSize) * (SizeWritten - BufferSize)`

Comment: I didn't understand the question in this case.

Comment: don't worry you understood it right and only you solved my problem, I just wanted to clean a little the operation that you've provided to don't transform the value into positive, and I just shown the operation together with other usefull calculation (the current chunk progress), don't worry all you did and your help was perfect, thanks again!